# Write a character at the end of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, streamwriter.write

Here's my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < bufferreader.Length; j++)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\yamald\Documents\Normal.data"))
    {
        //sw.Write();

        if (bufferreader.length != null)
        {
            sw.Write(bufferreader[j] + ",");
        }
        else
        {
            sw.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a "\n" at the end of array to my file? The `else` command does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place `sw.WriteLine("\n");` after the for loop.

As the loop stops when j = bufferreader.length, the if statement is always true.

Also, I think that bufferreader.length will never be null as you never modify this variable. I think what you need is :

```
if (bufferreader.length > j)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `sw` won't exist outside of the `for` loop, so it also needs to be declared probably instead of using `using`.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe put the for inside the using.

Comment: Yep, that would work too. In fact I changed my answer to reflect this. +1 to your answer for your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much. that is the solution `sw` should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just make the StreamWriter object before everything else and have it available until the loop has finished, then just write the `newline` after the loop, like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\yamald\Documents\Normal.data"))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bufferreader.Length; j++)
    {
        sw.Write(bufferreader[j] + ",");
    }
    sw.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

It's also probably better to use a `while` loop and do something like `while(bufferreader.length != null)` instead of the `for` loop and `if` statement, but that's up to you and I haven't used bufferreader in a while so wouldn't know the exact syntax for that.

However, the reason for why the `else` never gets executed is (as EoiFirst correctly said) that you're not actually changing bufferreader.length so it won't ever be null.

Comment: Thank you, I thought the `while` will not work once I am looking to write the content of the array into a file then write `\n` at the end for each row. That will produce a dataset.

Comment: You can still use a while loop, and write the `/n` after the loop (the same as you're doing after this solution). It will just be one while loop for each line. However, it won't really make much of a difference so don't worry about it.

Comment: I completely worry about your solution but I hope to give me an example. Why this negative point to my subject? `while(bufferreader.lenght != null) sw.Write(bufferreader[i] + ",");` Is that right?

Comment: That won't work because bufferreader.length will never become null (so it would create an infinite loop).
You could try `while(!bufferreader.EndOfStream) sw.Write(bufferreader.Next() + ",")`. I just found the method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Comment: Hi, could you give me a positive vote. I cann't post any question now